# Monitor performance/latency while copying file across Point 2 point circuit

Tags: networking, performance, monitoring, latency

This is my first post here, i did do a quick search couldn't find exactly what i was looking for.

I am copying a file from one server located in NW  part of the country to another server located in South. There is 1 Gb P2P circuit between two data centers. Is there a tool that can tell me how long it took to get through each hop while i am copying the file?

We have done enough troubleshooting and had the vendor out to  confirm P2P circuit speed and every thing came out clean. I am looking for a tool that will tell me where is the bottle neck in the transfer path. I have confirmed there is no issue with server or storage both on receiving and sending end.

Comment: Do a `pathping` in both directions ...

Comment: Installing an AppNeta device on either end would tell you.  They call their tool FlowView.  I think Auvik and Solarwinds have similar modules that are software based and possibly free.